# How to make autohotkey work in all programs except one

Tags: autohotkey

I have been testing autohotkey and I have found a way that depending on the program that is running, you can activate a certain keys functionality, but... how can I make a combination work in all programs except one?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a directive like `#IfWinActive` or `#IfWinExist`.  If so, you can invert the result using the opposite directives, `#IfWinNotActive` and `#IfWinNotExist`.

Comment: #IfWinNotActive is the solution i was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

To disable selected hotkeys or hotstrings automatically based on the type of window that is present, use `#IfWinActive/Exist`.

Check the documentation for more info https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm

Comment: Thanks for take a moment to answer my question. Actually that command work to use in some programs, #IfWinNotActive does what I want. Thanks you so much as well :)